# Yii RBAC implementation with "rights" extension

Tags: yii, rbac, yii-extensions

I am learning  Yii framework and I am creating a sample application also.

In my Application I have three user roles as

- Super admin
- Author
- and Registered Users

I want Authors to do CRUD operations to Articles.

I have extended all my Controllers with yii's RController and added the following code to the filters.

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        //'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        'rights',
    );
}
```

According to the Yii documentation and as I understand Yii should do automatic filter for me? But Even I log with an Super Admin account it says "Error 403 You are not authorized to perform this action."

Comment: I did this recently, using the Yii User Module, they have implemented a RBAC-like structure recently. It is also very easy to configure.

Comment: I've just re installed the rights extension as I couldn't find an answer. Once I re installed the extension it is now working. :)